# How can I parse an Ethereum block-level logsBloom?

Tags: events, json-rpc, logs, bloom-filter

I have been downloading blocks from EVM-based blockchains via the JSON-RPC API via `eth_getBlockByNumber`. In the block there is a `logsBloom` element which, if I understand this correctly, is an aggregate of the logs of every transaction in that block.

There are certain topics I want to search for, such as `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef` (token transfer). If I can search the block-level `logsBloom` filter for my topics in my software, then I can decide whether to go back to the blockchain to get any of the transaction-level logs and/or receipts.

I have limited API calls to my blockchain data provider, so I don't want to call `eth_getLogs` or `eth_getTransactionReceipt` for every single transaction on a blockchain since 99.9% of them are irrelevant to me and I simply can't send a million requests per day. I need this data historically back to genesis, so subscribing to real-time, filtered events is insufficient.

Is this possible? Can I parse and search the 256 byte block-level `logsBloom` data for "any transaction in the block which emitted a specific topic/event that I am asking for"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a topic might be possibly included in one of the transactions in the block, you must check if 3 bits in the logs bloom are set to 1.

Let's go through the example:

```yml
topic: 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
logsBloom: 0x0100000000000004000000000000100000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000080008000000000040000000002000000000040800000000000000000000200000000000004800000040000002000000000000000000081000000000000040000000001080020000200001000000000000000000040000004000000000000000000000000010000000008000000000000800008000000800000000008000000200000800000000000000200a000000200000000000100002004000000000000000000000000020000000000080000020000000800000000000004000000000000000080000004000
```

Get the `keccak256` of the topic: `0xada389e1fc24a8587c776340efb91b36e675792ab631816100d55df0b5cf3cbc`

> You can easily check if a specific bit is set to `1` with ByteMask, e.g. `00001000 == 8`. To check if a Byte (e.g. `0x33` or `51`) has the bit set to `1`, `(51 | 8) === 51`. Means when we `OR` all bits of the number `A` and number `B`, we should still get the `A`, as the same bit in `A` and `B` is `1`

So from the `0xada389e1fc24a85...` we have to find 3 ByteMasks and ByteIndexes to check in the bloom logs for.

We can refer to the source code, how the Bits are calculated which should be set to `1`.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/793f0f9ec860f6f51e0cec943a268c10863097c7/core/types/bloom9.go#L139

And do the same thing:

```typescript
function getNumber (hex: string, byteIndex: number, bytesCount: number = 1): number {
    let start = hex.startsWith('0x') ? 2 : 0;
    let i = start + byteIndex * 2;
    return parseInt(hex.substring(i, i + 2 * bytesCount), 16);
}

function getByteMasks (topic: string) {
    let hashBuf = keccak256(topic);
    let byte1Mask = 1 << (getNumber(hashBuf, 1) & 0x7);
    let byte2Mask = 1 << (getNumber(hashBuf, 3) & 0x7);
    let byte3Mask = 1 << (getNumber(hashBuf, 5) & 0x7);

    const BloomByteLength = 256;
    let byte1Pos = BloomByteLength - ((getNumber(hashBuf, 0, 2) & 0x7FF) >> 3) - 1;
    let byte2Pos = BloomByteLength - ((getNumber(hashBuf, 2, 2) & 0x7FF) >> 3) - 1;
    let byte3Pos = BloomByteLength - ((getNumber(hashBuf, 4, 2) & 0x7FF) >> 3) - 1;

    return [
        { index: byte1Pos, mask: byte1Mask },
        { index: byte2Pos, mask: byte2Mask },
        { index: byte3Pos, mask: byte3Mask },
    ];
}
```

And now, we can check our `logsBloom` if it matches the topic.

```typescript
let masks = getByteMasks(topic);

let bitsAreSet = masks.every((byte, i) => {
    let b = getNumber(logsBloom, byte.index);
    let has = (b | byte.mask) === b;
    return has;
});
```

If `bitsAreSet` is `false` we know that none of the transactions in the block has the `Transfer` log. But if it is `true`, it doesn't guarantee that the `Transfer` event is present, just it could be present.

Comment: Great explanation.  I'm going to try this out.

Comment: I think this is working.  I coded this in Java with the same logic and have ran a handful of values through it and confirmed that no logs for blocks WITHOUT transfers are returning a match (so no false positives).  I'm going to run a few thousand more tests to see how frequently it gives positive positives and possible positives for blocks that have and do not have transfers.  Thank you for the valuable info!

Answer (score 0):

The logs counted by a node provider such as Alchemy or Infura don't count every log/block in their single call limit, just the volume of logs matching the filters provided. Further, you can run these requests in a `for/each` or `do/while` loop to scan the blockchain in a macro sense, and further examine each `tokenTransfer` log returned.

For you to return `logsBloom` in an attempt to decode it, you wouldn't really get anywhere, because there's not really anything to 'decode':

Each tx has up to 4 topics, 3 of which represent bits, and are set depending on the hash of the topic in hand. Overall, this 2048bit string of `logsBloom` can be examined to see if the bits match the topic hash you are looking to find - if they don't match, that block didn't include a topic hash matching the one you are looking for. And even if they do, you would want to look further and ensure the block **does indeed** contain your topics, since these strings may contain false positives.

Bottom line - don't worry about rate throttling, just look explicitly for the topic has you're interested in. If you do reach a rate limit, which is I think >100,000 returns per day for Alchemy, you can go pro :)

Comment: I don't believe we can decode a logsBloom.  But can we say "does this bloom contain this event signature?"  By my understanding, it would answer either "no" or "maybe".  If the latter, then I would RPC call `eth_getTransactionReceipt` to confirm.  I'd still like my code to answer "do I need to get transaction receipts for any transactions in this block that match my list of event signatures (i.e. topic[0])?".  The caveat is that I may have 2,000 different event signatures in my list.  Hence, I'd like to pre-analyze this on our servers rather than making 2,000 eth_logs RPC calls per block.